# Как сделать шанс на выборку из бд без random?

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать шанс на выборку из бд без random?

Comment: случайную запись?

Comment: if(time()%2==0) { echo "Шанс есть!";
`

Comment: @Riolu, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: нет, вот например у меня есть таблица attack_pokemons и поле chans 
шанс от 1 до 100, нужно сделать чтобы этот шанс работал

Comment: Shrek, никак не могу додуматся как это сделать, кроме как с помощью рандома =(

Comment: @Riolu, а чем не устраивает рандом?

    (rand(0,99) + $chance) >= 100) ? echo 'Повезло' : 'Увы'

Comment: можно по звездам смотреть, по кофе...

Comment: не точным шансом =(

Comment: возможно три варианта: 1)да, 2)нет, 3)возможно. Иными словами да = 100%, нет = 0%, всё остальное - шанс есть.

Comment: Ладно, как я понял тут без рандома не обойтис =(

Answer (score 3):

```
$chance = 60;
$success = 0;
$failure = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    ((mt_rand(0, 99) + $chance) >= 100) ? $success++ : $failure++;
}

echo 'Success: '.$success.', Failure: '.$failure;
```

**[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/h82-n50)**